# Can my Filipina wife who has a 10 year B1 Visa travel with me in USA and later apply for a green card?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, b1-b2-visas

We both currently live and work in Saudi Arabia. We married in Seychelles. I am a US Citizen; she is a Philippines citizen. We plan to quit are jobs, then travel to USA for an extensive RV vacation. After the vacation we may move to Philippines or perhaps I will work in USA and later apply for her green card. Is this legal?
Thank you.

Comment: While the RV vacation is a travel question, the GC part (which seems to be the main question) is an immigration question - which we don't do here.    That is dealt with on the [Expatriates](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com) site

Comment: Traveling to the USA on a visitor visa **knowing full well** that you’re going to apply for a green card is misrepresentation/fraud and lead to being declared inadmissible and your petition denied. However if you’re not fully decided on whether you will apply for a green card or not, it is not fraud. Be careful of the new 90 Day Rule. https://www.nafsa.org/Professional_Resources/Browse_by_Interest/International_Students_and_Scholars/DOS_Expands_Presumption_of_Misrepresentation_Rule_to_90_Days/ . Make sure you don’t fall afoul of the law.

Comment: @HonoraryWorldCitizen while this is an immigration question I actually see no problem with starting the process when in the US on a visitor visa. As long as the marriage is valid and meets other requirements (health etc) you can apply for an adjustment of status (AOS) while in the US. Just making the application is not fraud - fraudulently making the application is fraud.

Comment: @PeterM You are mistaken. Read the USCIS memo. It’s pretty clear.

Comment: @HonoraryWorldCitizen Which part?  The memo talks about "Marrying" on a non-immigrant visa (but the OP is already married).  See also [this link](https://www.alllaw.com/articles/nolo/us-immigration/how-adjust-status-permanent-resident-after-marriage-citizen.html)

Comment: @PeterM someone who intends to immigrate is ineligible to enter the US in B status, so entering in B status when you plan to apply for permanent resident status, which requires declaring the purpose of your visit without mentioning applying for permanent resident status, is generally found to be fraud. It's allowed to enter without immigrant intent and then change your intent and apply for PR status.  As you can imagine, it's difficult to prove intent one way or the other, but it's generally better to avoid getting into a position where you have to.

Comment: @phoog This is why this is an immigration question and really requires the consultation of an immigration lawyer (which I am not).